# Como bloquear o Scroll do mouse no DataGridView?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6, rolamento, datagridview

Como desabilitar o ScrollBar em um grid no vb.net, está ocorrendo um problema e quero bloquear para corrigir isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso no evento [`MouseWheel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel.aspx). Veja um exemplo:

```vb-net
Private Sub DataGridView1_OnMouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) 
 Handles DataGridView1.MouseWheel
    Dim mwe As HandledMouseEventArgs = DirectCast(e, HandledMouseEventArgs)
    mwe.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: O que você postou é em C#, eu não estou conseguindo converter, poderia me ajudar? queria em vb.net mesmo.

Comment: @marcelo_drummer Não vi que era vb .NET, mas já arrumei.

Comment: me retornou esse erro: Error 8 Method 'Private Sub dgvApartamentos_OnMouseWheel(e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)' cannot handle event 'Public Event MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)' because they do not have a compatible signature. C:\Users\Marcelo\Dropbox\TCC\in_hoteis\frmQUARTOS.vb 169 97 IN_HOTEIS

Comment: @marcelo_drummer Já arrumei também =)

Comment: @marcelo_drummer Funcionou?

Comment: estou usando um framework que se chama metro framework, a programação é a mesma do dgv padrão, não funcionou, você conhece o framework?

Comment: @marcelo_drummer Não conheço. Já tentou isto no DGV padrão?